# How do I use the EventBuilder to create an event?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Suppose I wanted to emit

```
public event PropertyChangedHandler PropertyNameChanged;
```

How would I do this? Would I need to define a backing field like I would a property? I can't find a single example of how to use the EventBuilder and how do I actually raise an event?

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is old question and this answer will probably never be accepted, but I get here from Google so probably other people will get here to. Just for those people, here is a correct answer:
To create and event you have to:

1. Create Field `{EventName}`
2. Create Event with the same name `{EventName}`
3. Create add and remove accessors (methods) `add_{EventName}` and `remove_{EventName}`
4. Create raise method with some arbitrary name (or do not, since this step is optional)

Second and forth is covered by Dmitry answer, but here is a complete code. Of course you have to change `EventName` and `EventType` for values correct for your event.

1. Field for event

```
var field = typeBuilder.DefineField("{EventName}", typeof({EventType}), FieldAttributes.Private);
```

2. Event

```
var eventInfo = typeBuilder.DefineEvent("{EventName}", EventAttributes.None, typeof({EventType}));
```

3. Add accessor and remove accessor; they are very similar.

   ```
   var addMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("add_{EventName}",
       MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
       CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis,
       typeof(void),
       new[] { typeof({EventType}) });
   var generator = addMethod.GetILGenerator();
   var combine = typeof(Delegate).GetMethod("Combine", new[] { typeof(Delegate), typeof(Delegate) });
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, combine);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof({EventType}));
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   eventInfo.SetAddOnMethod(addMethod);
   ```

   ```
   var removeMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("remove_{EventName}",
           MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
           CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis,
           typeof(void),
           new[] { typeof({EventType}) });
   var remove = typeof(Delegate).GetMethod("Remove", new[] { typeof(Delegate), typeof(Delegate) });
   var generator = removeMethod.GetILGenerator();
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, remove);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(PropertyChangedEventHandler));
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   eventInfo.SetRemoveOnMethod(removeMethod);
   ```
4. Raise method. Not required, but there is really no point for creating event if you do not have method to raise it. Unless you are doing some hocus-pocus with reflection or calling value of event Delegate.
   Anyway here is the code for this method. Of course you have to obtain correct constructor of some `XXXEventArgs` type, that is used inside of event, first. Name of this raise method also may be different, but following some pattern is generally better idea (like below):

   ```
   var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("On{EventName}",
       MethodAttributes.Family | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
       MethodAttributes.NewSlot, typeof(void),
       new[] { typeof(string) });
   var generator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
   var returnLabel = generator.DefineLabel();
   var eventArgsCtor = typeof({XXXEventArgs}).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
   generator.DeclareLocal(typeof({EventType}));
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, returnLabel);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, eventArgsCtor);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(PropertyChangedEventHandler).GetMethod("Invoke"));
   generator.MarkLabel(returnLabel);
   generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
   eventInfo.SetRaiseMethod(methodBuilder);
   return methodBuilder;
   ```

   Also this method do not have be virtual, or protected (`MethodAttributes.Family`), but it is better to have this method non-public and overridable. Types of parameter also have to be different and compatible with `XXXEventArgs` type constructor. You can also have more parameters in this method but I advice against it since it makes IL more complicated (you should do as little in IL as possible as favor for yourself and your sanity).

Comment: At least I can give you an upvote for the better answer! Thanks a lot! ;-)

Comment: Suggested Edit: The double `generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)` took me a while to reconstruct the resulting stack in my head. The duplicate `this` is used all the way down in `generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);`. Serious brainfuck! Using a local makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Toxantron: yeah it would be better, but I do not matter how "clean" you will make IL. after 6 months you will have problem recalling what is it all about :) If this works - do not change it!

Answer (score 1):

```
  TypeBuilder myClass =
     myModule.DefineType("MyClass", TypeAttributes.Public);

  MethodBuilder onPropertyNameChanged= myClass.DefineMethod("OnPropertyNameChanged",
     MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new Type[]{typeof(Object)});
  ILGenerator onPropertyNameChangedIl= onPropertyNameChanged.GetILGenerator();
  onPropertyNameChangedIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

  // Create the event.
  EventBuilder propertyNameChanged= myClass.DefineEvent("PropertyNameChanged", EventAttributes.None,
     typeof(PropertyChangedHandler)); //should be declared before
  propertyNameChanged.SetRaiseMethod(onPropertyNameChanged);

  myClass.CreateType();
```

Comment: I tried to add an event handler to an instance of the type via t.GetEvent("FirstNameChanged").AddEventHandler(o, (Action)TestMethod); but then I get the following error message: Cannot add the event handler since no public add method exists for the event. Did I miss anything? I cannot add it using dynamic variable because it doesn't support += / -=